# Regex: Matching only the first occurrence?

Tags: regex, matching

I have a lot lines like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxf_article1_something
http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxi_article2_something
```

How to match `http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxf_` ? I try this but it doesn't work.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/video/.*_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
http://www\.mywebsite\.com/video/.*?_
```

Try this. Make `*` non greedy.

Better use

```
http://www\.mywebsite\.com/video/[^_]*_
```

Comment: plus 1 for mention of negation based regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also.

```
http:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com\/video\/(?:(?!_).)*_
```